# Printing from a web page

Tags: html, css, printing

I have made a tedious form . The height of the wrapper is width:850px height:1100px which is letter size at 150dpi. But while printing I get little data from the second page. How can I print only one particular page on 1 paper and 2nd on another. Do i need to create a print css, if so how do I define to print only 1 page per paper.
Thank you This is my link. 
http://www.spheretekk.com/form1/form1.html

```
@media print{ .wrapper{background-color:Transparent;color:Black;}
body{background-color:Transparent;}

}
```

Comment: A web page is not a representation of a printed page. Use PDF if you want to control the pages

Comment: I do want to save as pdf, but I don't want contents of second page on the first page. For that I created wrapper and made 2 wrappers.

Comment: You need to DELIVER==create on server the PDF not save as.